# How to use secret keys in Azure Machine Learning Service pipelines

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am using Azure Machine Learning services and the [pipeline functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/concept-ml-pipelines) for data preparation, training and testing of my Machine Learning models. However, during my data preparation step, I need to connect to a database and I want to find a way to pass my secret passwords or keys without writing them in plain text in my script files.

Locally, I make use of environment variables for using secret passwords and keys, but to my best knowledge, this is impossible in the pipeline infrastructure, since Conda doesn't support passing environment variables. If anyone can confirm or deny this, it would be helpful.

In the Azure Machine Learning services in the Azure Portal, I have found a 'key vault' resource, that is created automatically when I create a 'Machine Learning service workspace' resource. This seems to be exactly what I need. Is it? And if so, how do I use it?

If neither of the above solves my issue, is there any other way to safely use secret passwords and keys in my scripts, without writing them in plain text in the scripts?

EDIT: I realize my question have a strong focus on database connections. However, the question is really about any kinds of secrets or passwords, not just database credentials. As have been pointed out in an answer, that could be worth mentioning here, is that Azure SQL database connections can (and should) be solved using the [DataTransferStep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-steps/azureml.pipeline.steps.data_transfer_step.datatransferstep?view=azure-ml-py).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using environment variables, you could just pass the credentials via the `arguments`parameter:

```
pipeline_step = PythonScriptStep(
    script_name='train.py',
    arguments=['--keyvault_name', 'MyKV', '--secret_name', 'MyPW'], ...
```

And define the script arguments in `train.py` as follows:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('train')
parser.add_argument('--keyvault_name')
parser.add_argument('--secret_name')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

You can then use the variables `args.keyvault_name` and `args.secret_name` in your script. You can use these values to read the password from the Key Vault. Of course, you must first create the Key Vault and store the password there. In addition, you must also ensure that AML Workspace has the permission to read secrets from the Key Vault.

Of course, you could also pass the password in the script argument in plain text, but this is not advisable.

Comment: This might be a feasible solution. I hadn't really given it enough thought yet. However, I haven't yet understood how to activate the Key Vault. There is one created along with the workspace, but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it.

Comment: This might be a feasible solution but it doesn't work. Neither keyvault name nor key vault uri work. It is a strange situation that there is only one attempt to provide a solution of this problem - it seems that Microsoft doen't care about this problem.

Comment: @AlexanderKulikov what do you mean that the name or uri don't work? They are not passed on to the script, but are empty?

Note that you can read Key Vault secrets with Python by following the instructions in this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-python

Answer (score 1):

What kind of database do you use? If it's Azure SQL, you could use DataTransferStep instead of passing secrets. The relevant classes are:

[DataTransferStep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-steps/azureml.pipeline.steps.data_transfer_step.datatransferstep?view=azure-ml-py)

[DataReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.data_reference.datareference?view=azure-ml-py)

[AzureSqlDataBaseDataStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.azure_sql_database_datastore.azuresqldatabasedatastore?view=azure-ml-py)

Comment: Thank you. I should perhaps have been more clear about that. My question is broader that just database credentials, however, so it's still an open question.

Comment: Makes sense. I filed a feature request for supporting secrets in remote runs.

Answer (score 1):

Passing secrets to remote runs is now supported, as of Azure ML SDK version 1.0.57, through azureml.core.keyvault.KeyVault object:

See Using Secrets in Remote Runs section [in this notebook](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/manage-azureml-service/authentication-in-azureml/authentication-in-azureml.ipynb)

Comment: Awesome. I wish I could have been there to try it out, but unfortunately I am no longer working with Azure. I hope, though, that I was not the only one waiting for support for secrets.

Comment: Since I can not try it out myself, I don't feel comfortable enough to mark your answer as the solution. Perhaps any second opinion can help me be comfortable?